# How to update query/data source when cell change value

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to create Table which takes parameters from another table on the same spreadsheet.
Always, I create new Query, and load it into the same spreadsheet with main table, it reates new spreadsheet anyway, and additionaly creates reference to that table in main spreadsheet. Like on the screenshot below:

[image]

I would like to use both tables in the same spreadsheet.

**Additionally I would like to update query when when user change value in spreadsheet.**
Actually when user click "refresh" it changes value in spreadsheet to those from query.

Comment: Update your question with more details in what you are trying to do. Provide sample data and what the scenario is. Share any PowerQuery code etc... Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I know what you're after - your query looks at the table in the screenshot and takes those values to load that file into the query.

You'll need a function to look at the table.

**fParameter**

```
let Parameter=(TableName,RowNumber) =>
    let
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=TableName]}[Content],
        value = Source{RowNumber-1}[Value] //[Value] is the column header in the table.
    in
        value
in Parameter
```

and use that function to grab the values from the table.
This gets the value from *Table1* row 1, and *Table1* row 2.

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(Text.From(fParameter("Table1",1) & Text.From(fParameter("Table1",2)))),[Delimiter=",", Columns=5, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
in
    Source
```